# Parse.com query is too slow and needs to be faster

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

My Parse.com query is too slow, below code is 1 network call. Therefore I want to execute 3 queries in parallel:

1. Query row 0 - 200
2. Query row 201 - 400
3. Query row 401 - 500

This is the current code:

```
    public static void readBusShelters() {

            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(BusShelter.TABLE_NAME);
            query.setLimit(500);
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {

                }
            });
    }
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the parse query in an `AsyncTask` with a callback and execute on the thread pool to enable tasks to run in parallel.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnTaskCompleted {

  @Override
  public void onTaskCompleted(List<ParseObject> response) {

  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    new FetchParseQueryTask(MainActivity.this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new PagingOptions(0, 200));
    new FetchParseQueryTask(MainActivity.this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new PagingOptions(1, 200));
    new FetchParseQueryTask(MainActivity.this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, new PagingOptions(2, 200));
  }
}
```

The callback:

```
public interface OnTaskCompleted {
    void onTaskCompleted(List<ParseObject> response);
}
```

Sample implementation of `FetchParseQueryTask` class:

```
public class FetchParseQueryTask extends AsyncTask<PagingOptions, Void, List<ParseObject>> {

  private OnTaskCompleted mTaskCompleted;

  public FetchParseQueryTask(OnTaskCompleted activityContext){
    mTaskCompleted = activityContext;
  }

  @Override
  protected List<ParseObject> doInBackground(PagingOptions... params) {
    PagingOptions pagingOptions = params[0];
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("TABLE_NAME");

    query.setLimit(pagingOptions.getLimit());
    query.setSkip(pagingOptions.getPage() * pagingOptions.getLimit());

    try {
        return query.find();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(List<ParseObject> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if (mTaskCompleted != null) {
        mTaskCompleted.onTaskCompleted(result);
    }
  }
}
```

`PagingOptions` class:

```
public class PagingOptions {

  private int mPage;

  private int mLimit;

  public PagingOptions(int page, int limit)
  {
    mPage = page;
    mLimit = limit;
  }

  public int getPage() {
    return mPage;
  }

  public void setPage(int mPage) {
    this.mPage = mPage;
  }

  public int getLimit() {
    return mLimit;
  }

  public void setLimit(int mLimit) {
    this.mLimit = mLimit;
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear Clive, thanks a lot. I'm adding a constructor with a callback to the FetchParseQueryTask to get the results back. That's correct, right?

Comment: Yeah, I have updated the answer with an example callback